# SQL select query two rows combining

Tags: sql

I have two tables called A, B. I write SQL query to retrieve data from A, B. It is as follows:

```
SELECT  A.No ,
    A.ItemCode, 
        case when B.Year = 1 then SUM(B.Sale_Amount)  end as "1Year",
        case when B.Year = 2 then SUM(B.Sale_Amount)  end as "2Year",
        case when B.Year = 3 then SUM(B.Sale_Amount)  end as "3Year"
FROM  A  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  B ON B.ID  = A.CODE    
GROUP BY
A."No",
A."ItemCode",
B."Year"
```

This gives following output:

[image: result]

But I need these three rows select in two rows as follows:

[image: reslut wanted]

Comment: remove group by year. As you are grouping by year but second and third row has different year value thus its not grouping them in one row as you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial pivot without pivot operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542711/partial-pivot-without-pivot-operator)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer

```
SELECT  A.No ,
A.ItemCode, 
    SUM(case when B.Year = 1 then B.Sale_Amount  end) as [1Year],
    SUM(case when B.Year = 2 then B.Sale_Amount  end) as [2Year],
    SUM(case when B.Year = 3 then B.Sale_Amount  end) as [3Year]
```

FROM  A
LEFT OUTER JOIN  B ON B.ID  = A.CODE
GROUP BY A.No,A.ItemCode